# Error consolidation/annotated-command

Tags: drush, composer

Trying to install Drush using Composer, i get an error concerning consolidation/annotated-command. What does it mean "locked at 2.0.3" and "requires 2.8.1"?

This is the error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1

- Installation request for drush/drush dev-master -> satisfiable by drush/drush[dev-master].
- Conclusion: remove consolidation/annotated-command 2.0.3
- Conclusion: don't install consolidation/annotated-command 2.0.3
- drush/drush dev-master requires consolidation/annotated-command ^2.8.1 -> satisfiable by consolidation/annotated-command[2.8.1, 2.8.2].
- Can only install one of: consolidation/annotated-command[2.8.1, 2.0.3].
- Can only install one of: consolidation/annotated-command[2.8.2, 2.0.3].
- Installation request for consolidation/annotated-command (locked at 2.0.3) -> satisfiable by consolidation/annotated-command[2.0.3].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: You have something already installed that’s locked to a version of a dependency that drush needs a more recent version of. See what’s in your global composer file

Comment: @Clive, thx for pointing me to _composer.lock_. But how to overcome this constraint? _Composer info_ shows v2.8.1 for _annotated-command_.

Comment: You can't overcome the constraint, it's a hard constraint. You'll need to find the package that depends on the old version and remove/upgrade it. Try running `composer prohibits consolidation/annotated-command 2.8.1`, hopefully that'll give you some info to go on

Comment: The command results in "no installed package depending on _consolidation/annotated-command_ in versions not matching 2.8.1"
When I changed to 2.0.3, the result is "__ root __  -  requires  consolidation/annotated-command (2.8.1)"

Answer (score 1):

I get this error after changing the minimum version of drush/drush to `~9.0` in my `composer.json` and running `composer update drush/drush` afterwards.

I solved it by just executing `composer require drush/drush:~9.0` which lead to the error message `drush/drush 9.5.x-dev requires symfony/config ^3.4`, so I had to execute `composer require symfony/config:^3.4` before `composer require drush/drush:~9.0` could be finished successful.

Don't know if this is the only way or best practice to solve such a dependency conflict but in short this worked for me:

1. `composer require symfony/config:^3.4`
2. `composer require drush/drush:~9.0`